# How to use C++ for transmitting data using xbee?

Tags: c++, xbee

For a project i need to establish 2 way xbee communication. But I have a problem sending data from my pc. I use cpp with termios to transmitt a char array but on the xbee tx pin I do only get a signal (I observe this on an oscilloscope) when one of the chars is 0x0A.

The XBee module is on a 30011662-02 board, which is connected to my pc via usb.
I thought maybe this is some kind of starting parameter needed by the xbee board to transmit but couldnt find any information on this.

```cpp
ctx->debug = debug;
    //open USB port for read/write and check success
    ctx->fd = open(devFileName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY); //opens the usb port for reading
    if (ctx->fd < 0) {
        cerr << "Could not open the USB Port. Try adding User to group dialout!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    //is the opened port a terminal?
    if(!isatty(ctx->fd)) {
        close(ctx->fd);
        errno = ENOTTY;
        return 0;
    }

    //setup termios
    tcgetattr(ctx->fd, &(ctx->oldtio));

    cfmakeraw(&newtio);
    cfsetispeed(&newtio, baudrate);
    cfsetospeed(&newtio, baudrate);

    tcsetattr(ctx->fd, TCSANOW, &newtio); //connects fd to newtio
    tcflush(ctx->fd, TCIOFLUSH);    //discards data not transmitted or received
    lseek(ctx->fd, 0, SEEK_END);

    ctx->bufIO = fdopen(ctx->fd, "r+");

    bool connection_status=0;
    unsigned char frame_id=0x00;
    unsigned char checksum=0xff;
    int j=0;
    while(!connection_status){
        checksum=0xFF;      
        unsigned char buffer[] = {
                                  0x7E, //start delimiter  
                                  0x00,0x07,//length of the data packet 
                                  0x01,//API identifier (refer to XBee module manual for further details)
                                  frame_id++, //frame id 
                                  0x00,0x0B,//destination address   
                                  0x00,//options 
                                  0x02,0x03,//data: 0,receiver address,mode
                                  0x00};            //checksumm

        for(unsigned int i=0;i<sizeof(buffer);i++){
            checksum-=buffer[i];
        }
        cout << buffer << endl;
        j++;
        buffer[10]=checksum;

        fwrite(buffer,sizeof(char),sizeof(buffer),ctx->bufIO);

        usleep(2000000);
    }
```

I do expect to see data on the xbee tx pin in every itteration of the while loop but so far it only works when frame_id is 0x0A or i manually enter 0x0A in the array buffer. But still it does not seem to be sending the correct data. Maybe you have some hints for me.

Comment: It's not still in AtAt mode? As 0x0a is a carriage return.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have just checked the module settings. I have API enabled and the 0x01 is definitly the identifier for a transmitt. so I guess this should not be the problem

Comment: Check you checksum value.  It should start after the Frame Length (on the Frame Type field, `i=3`).  Summing all of the bytes after the length, including the packet's checksum byte, should result in 0x00.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a setting (maybe `O_NDELAY`?) for the serial port (tty) and it's in line mode.  You might want to look at [this serial driver](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library/blob/master/ports/posix/xbee_serial_posix.c) used in an Open Source XBee Host Library written in ANSI C (instead of C++).  You might even be able to build your application on top of that library.  At the very least, you could compile the samples and see if they work with your module as a way to verify your wiring and XBee configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am using cfmakeraw to get it to raw mode, but it looks like it still is in line mode yes. Dont ask me why... I had a short look into the library, but it will take some time till  I figured it all out i guess.It is a little messy and not easy understand for me.  As I am already receiving data the wiring should not be a big problem.